# How to create filtering paging with DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, filtering, dynamodb-queries

I would like to have the opinion of a professional in DynamoDB. Because I don't understand how other developers to manage query with limit and filtering.

This is my table informations:

**Table name:** Posts 
**Partition key:** Type (STRING) 
**Sort key:** id (STRING)

My table have other fields like: title, description, status, created_at, etc.. 
I have for example 10000 Posts.

When I try to retrieve posts 15 by 15, I have no problem. To manage pagination I use the **LastEvaluatedKey**.

I have a problem when I try to do the same thing with filter. 
Example of request: recover the posts where type = "archives" and where status = 2 with a pagination 15 by 15

I think, DynamoDB retrieves 15 posts and then performs a filter. 
So, if in the 15 posts recovered only 3 have the status = 2 then I will not have 15 posts but 3.

I want to know if it's normal behavior. Should I create a loop and get posts until I have 15 posts ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think, DynamoDB retrieves 15 posts and then performs a filter.
> So, if in the 15 posts recovered only 3 have the status = 2 then I will not have 15 posts but 3.

yes this is correct, and also the documentation says so:- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html

> I want to know if it's normal behavior. Should I create a loop and get
> posts until I have 15 posts ?

Yes, it's the intended behavior, but it will incur the higher RCUs because underlying you will consume RCU for fetching the data post query operation.

What you can do is:-

1. Maintain composite keys, if the filter pattern is known beforehand
2. Explore GSIs, which provide eventual consistencies, but will save you from the write cost, i.e. because if you do multi-row writes you might end up using transact API of the dynamo, thus leading to higher WCU.